# Alert for New resources in Azure

Tags: azure, resources, monitor, alerts, azure-data-explorer

Need to create an alert in Azure Monitor using Kusto Query, that would trigger if any new resource is added to the subscription.

I tried adding alert from the portal, but that specifies any of the resource, whereas the expected alert should be triggered if any kind of resource is added to the resource group. Alos, i could not find any suitable Event ID for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Event Grid should be the solution to what you want to achieve. You can can instance notifications on resource events, such as `Microsoft.Resources.ResourceWriteSuccess`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-subscriptions

You can subscribe to those events for example with an Azure Logic App or a Function and do your custom logic in there.

This tutorial should provide you with a good starting point: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/monitor-virtual-machine-changes-event-grid-logic-app

Answer (score -1):

@Jothi Sree : This can be easily achieved by the Azure Activity Log Alerts. It is easy to configure.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-alerts

This can also be pushed to Log analytics workspace where you should see the activity log related tables and you can write kusto log alerts as well.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-collect

Comment: I'm afraid the functionality in the activity logs wouldn't allow you to have a single catch all alert for any new resource, if you needed to know anything about the resource you'd have to create multiple alerts for each resource type you wish to monitor

Comment: @Simon it should as the Activity log is at the subscription level and you can route this events to Log analytics and alerts it from there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log  In case if this spawns the current subscription then you need to use Azure light house or policies to get the relevant logs.